# Add values from list to a list of dicts (as new key-val in each dict)

Tags: python

Suppose you have a list of dicts:

```
l = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 5, "b": 1}, {...}, {...}]
```

And a list, where we know the position of each item is relevant to the list of dicts above:

```
results = [True, False, True, True]
```

I want to add the result as a new key "result" to each dict in the original list, so that `l` will be:

```
[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "result": True}, {"a": 5, "b": 1, "result": False}, {..., "result": True}, {..., "result": True}]
```

I know I can use the index in the results to add result in the original list of dicts, like:

```
for ix, val in enumerate(results):
    l[ix]["result"] = val
```

This usually means I am modifying lists in-place inside methods/functions, or I am recreating these lists and returning the new copy, which seems a bit inefficient. Is there a better way to do it (maybe with zip or something)? Is it worth overcomplicating it or should I leave this pattern alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the lists in place.

A version with zip might be more aesthetically pleasing...

```py
for element, result in zip(l, results):
    element["result"] = result
```

Either way, I find it good practice to avoid premature optimization. The right time to optimize is when you have collected evidence via measurement that a section of code does not meet performance requirements.